# Allowing/denying apps per user linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, parental-controls

Is there a way, long if need be, to have a whitelist on linux mint for one or multiple groups/users of applications that they can be opened? Example: User 1 and User 2 can only open firefox whereas User 3 can open Firefox and libre office. Everything else is restricted to all users except for User 4, who can open and do what ever he wants.

Answer (score 2):

Classic way to control who can run a given executable `foo` is like this:

1. With `chown` make `foo` executable belong to `foo` group.
2. With `chmod` set the permissions so only the owner and the group can execute the file.
3. Assign users to groups as you wish.

This is not a good solution if you need to do this for many (all?) executable files in your system. If you want to restrict a given user to a narrow set of possible commands then you should research the topic of [restricted shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402638).

I have found [bdsh](https://raymii.org/s/software/bdsh.html). Looks promising (although I have never used it myself):

> bdsh is a shell where you whitelist commands and only those commands can be executed.

Some other (newer?) similar solutions may exist.

---

EDIT: also read *[How to limit user commands in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21498667)* on Stack Overflow.

Comment: would that allow them to only open firefox? I understand chmod but chown is a little more confusing to me.

Comment: Sorry. I've been working on this for months and words are getting mixed up in my head. I need to make an account that can only access a specific program. Everything else need to be blocked. I'm setting up a small school system at my job. I need every computer to connect to a DC, however I don't want them bypassing that by just using the linux computer's programs. If that makes sense

Comment: @rvcabc What do you mean: "DC"? I want to be sure there's no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: That sounds about right. By DC I mean domain controller.

Comment: @rvcabc Well, my answer may not be the best possible. I think you should edit your question and place all these explanation there. They really helped me to understand your problem better. Other users should see them in the question body, they won't read all the comments. After you do this, you may delete your comments here.

Comment: @rvcabc I added a link to another question, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but possible solution:

1. remove the 'executable' bit for general users on /usr/bin (and maybe some others)(this prevents them to read anything in /usr/bin)
2. create a directory with hardlinks to the authorized apps in /usr/bin
3. set their PATH to point to it